# How can I find what nodes are causing 404 errors?

Tags: nodes

I'm watching entries in my *Top 'page not found'* report page steadily rise.

I am unable to fix the 404 errors because I have several hundreds of nodes, and there is no indication of which node is causing the problem.

Is there a way I can see which nodes are causing the 404 errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a the "Recent log messages" report and apply a filter to show you only the "page not found" logs. You will then see a list of pages not found and you can click on the message to find out more details about it.

[image: Recent log messages filter]

If the problem is that a lot of pages change their path then you might want to use the "Path Redirect" module (http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) if you are using Drupal 6 or the "Redirect" module (http://drupal.org/project/redirect) if you are using Drupal 7 to let search engines know about the new path of the content.

**Note:** if you have clean URL setup make sure it is working and you are not missing the .htaccess file. It happen to me once when I move a site from dev to production and I didn't copy the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) and visit `admin/config/search/redirect/404` on your site. You will see a report like this, which makes it very easy to identify the most "popular" missing pages, and create matching redirects to the correct location(s).

[image: example redirect 404s report]